# How do I get a user's profile picture path on c++ (winapi)

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to make a ui like in https://www.reddit.com/r/unixporn/comments/p7oloc/13gaps_my_first_complete_rice_on_i3

I know how to get the active wallpaper with registry.

(HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WallPaper)

I'd like to get the active profile picture directory.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Were you able to locate an according API on MSDN?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) with `rfid` = `FOLDERID_AccountPictures`.